# Show that f reaches it's supremum

Tags: calculus, analysis

I have a function : $\ln\bigg(x^2+\dfrac34\bigg) - x^2$ and i have to show that this function reaches it's supremum. 
I thought finding lim in $-\infty$ and $\infty$ will give me an answer, but lim of this is so hard to calculate. Moveover, i can't use derivatives, although i know them... Is there a possibility to show it without using derivatives? If no, is there easier way to show it with lim? Thanks

Comment: Is this function defined on $\mathbb{R}$? Generally, what is the domain of this function?

Comment: Sorry : I input a stupidity !

Comment: Finding the limit of $f(x)=\ln\left(x^2+\frac{3}{4}\right)-x^2$ for $x\to\infty$ and $x\to-\infty$ is not a correct method. What you need to do is find a $x_0$ such, that $f(x_0)=\sup f$.

Comment: If a function reaches a supremum then it has a maximum value. Hard to find without differentiating.

Comment: Yes. Show the limit at $\pm\infty$ is $-\infty$. Find $M$ so that the function has value less than $\ln 3/4$ off $[-M,M]$.  Show the function attains its supremum somewhere in $[-M,M]$. (Note you need not actually find it explicitly.)

Comment: One way to show this would without computing the limit would be to compute a value - say $f(0)$ and show that $f(x)$ is less than this outside a suitable closed interval (so estimating the size of $f$ would help). Then use the theorem that a continuous function on a closed interval attains its bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice $e^x \geq x + 1 \implies e^{x-1} \geq x  \implies x - 1 \geq \ln x $. Replace $x$ by $x^2 + \frac{3}{4} $, then

$$ x^2 + \frac{3}{4} - 1 \geq \ln\bigg( x^2 + \frac{3}{4}\bigg) \implies -\frac{1}{4} \geq \ln\bigg( x^2 + \frac{3}{4}\bigg) - x^2$$

Comment: Hey, thanks, i was trying to do another example with same method (those are old tasks from exams) it is: 
$ln(e^x + e^9) - e^x$ and $x>0$
So, $x-1 \geq ln x$ and i get $e^x+e^9-1 \geq ln(e^x+e^9) \rightarrow e^9-1 \geq ln(e^x+e^9)-e^x$, but wolfram says that global maxima doesn't exist, any help?

Answer (score 2):

These limits aren't really that bad. The key here is the notion of an *equivalent*. Here, we have $x^2+\frac{3}{4}\sim x^2$, which means that the ratio between those two functions tends to $1$ at infinity, which you can prove quite easily. Basically: when $x^2$ is huge, who cares about the extra $3/4$?

Since we can write:

$$\ln\bigg(x^2+3/4\bigg)=\ln\bigg(x^2\frac{x^2+3/4}{x^2}\bigg)$$

And that ratio tends to $1$, we can conclude:

$\lim \ln(x^2+3/4) = \lim \ln(x^2)$

Combined with the fact that $\ln x - x \to -\infty$, you can show that your limit is equal to $-\infty$.